# SharePoint 3.0 Migration to SharePoint Server 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-services

We're just using SharePoint Services 3.0 for maybe a year. Now we want to upgrade this server to actual SharePoint 2010.

Is there a solution for upgrading the Database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look [HERE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee617150.aspx).

Comment: And you need to read [this](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262747.aspx) too

Comment: Just posting a link is bad practice.